# Ibatis + j2ee + web service layer + statless bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ibatis

I have a j2ee project using ibatis to connect to the database and stateless bean to create web service and it works but i have a doubt

every time i call the service:

1. parse the ibatis xml configuration file.
2. ibatis connect to the database
3. and generate the query.

It is possible to avoid 1 and 2? or at least 1?

What is the correct way to do it?.

I think that may be it is possible to call the ibatis xml once in a stateful ejb?

Thanks.

Comment: More details please. Which version of iBatis? Any other framework except standard stateless EJB's?

Comment: im not using any other framework but i will try with spring.

Comment: If you use Spring, that would greatly ease your use of iBatis in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Logically speaking, the configuration file should be parsed only once and the resulting object be stored in an application scoped variable. The simplest but frowned upon way for that would be using Singletons. The preferred way would be to use some sort of dependency injection framework like Guice or Spring.
2. iBatis would require a connection object to connect to the database so this can't be avoided. How are you currently handling connection management in your code?

Comment: I don't understand the second point, the connection is configured in the ibatis's xml (oracle) and it it stored in a SqlMapClient.

Comment: @magallanes: There are multiple ways of plugging a datasource with iBatis. If you use a POOLED configuration, a pool of connections would be created and when a request comes in, instead of creating a connection, one would be picked from the pool and that would greatly improve the response time.

Comment: not now but i will connect through jndi (pooled) so it is not all the problem but to parse the xml.  In Jboss i managed to do a singleton so apparently i will stick with it.   And about spring, i am tied to ejb.